# How to include an HTML page into another HTML page without frame/iframe?

Tags: html

I want to include an HTML page inside an HTML page.  Is it possible?

I don't want to do it in PHP, I know that in PHP, we can use `include` for this situation, how can I achieve the same purely in HTML without using the `iframe` and `frame` concept?

Comment: You can use object instead of iframe, but it's no better. What do you have against iframe?

Comment: duplicate of [Include another HTML file in a HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file)

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/the-simplest-ways-to-handle-html-includes/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you're just trying to stick in your own HTML from another file, and you consider a **[Server Side Include](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/ssi.html)** to be "pure HTML" (because it kind of looks like an HTML comment and isn't using something "dirty" like PHP):

```
<!--#include virtual="/footer.html" -->
```

Comment: This isnt a pure HTML solution is it?

Comment: Hey, here i got a idea, i have included the whole content inside the javascript - document.write. then place the javascript file inside the html. It working

Comment: If using Server Side Include (SSI) you need to be conscious that it may be difficult for your documents to be cached since the modified time and content length are all dynamic. With Apache you can use XBitHack Full (on UNIX) or mod_expires to set expiry times. I didn't end up using SSI for this reason.

Comment: Just a remark. You need a server with SSI installed on the server for this to work, which is not always the case.

Comment: I would `#include file` if it's in a higher directory in the site.

Answer (score 47):

You can use an object element

```
<object type="text/html" data="urltofile.html"></object>
```

or, on your local server, AJAX can return a string of HTML (responseText) that you can use to document.write a new window, or edit out the head and body tags and add the rest to a div or another block element in the current page.

Comment: Unfortunately using OBJECT or EMBED tags also introduces HEAD/BODY tags in the included HTML, even if you don't have them in the sub-HTML. This will break validation and also cause spacing issues so this is not the best solution.

Comment: @geneb. Thanks. Exactly what I was wondering. I can't figure out why you'd ever want these extraneous tags introduced. You got any idea?

Answer (score 30):

If you mean client side then you will have to use JavaScript or frames.
Simple way to start, try [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

```
$("#links").load("/Main_Page #jq-p-Getting-Started li");
```

More at [jQuery Docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load)

If you want to use IFrames then start with Wikipedia on [IFrames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iframes)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
        <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
        The material below comes from the website http://example.com/
        <iframe src="http://example.com/" height="200">
            Alternative text for browsers that do not understand IFrames.
        </iframe>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, here i got a idea, i have included the whole content inside the javascript - document.write. then place the javascript file inside the html. It working

Comment: I'm surprised that it's 2022 but we still don't have client-side SSI without IFrames and JavaScript, but have WebComponents. LOL

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/the-simplest-ways-to-handle-html-includes/ -- an entire article on this subject.

Answer (score 28):

You could use HTML5 for this:

```html
<link rel="import" href="/path/to/file.html">
```

---

**Update – July 2020:** This feature is no longer supported by most major browsers, and is generally considered obsolete. See [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/imports) for the list of browsers which do still support it.

Comment: this is only for webcomponent polymer

Comment: @Joyal no, this is part of HTML5, some browsers are already support it, but for those that don't, you can use polymer to polyfill it. http://caniuse.com/#search=import

Comment: @muis , the above code will only work if you load a page from the same domain, else you get the foloowing error : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. This is restricted due to security reasons. For more details see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: This won't work on a lot of web browsers, if that is an issue for someone (like me): http://caniuse.com/#feat=imports

Comment: This is obsolete since Google Chrome 73. Try to avoid this solution. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports

Answer (score 11):

```
<iframe src="page.html"></iframe>
```

You will need to add some styling to this iframe. You can specify width, height, and if you want it to look like a part of the original page include `frameborder="0"`.

There is no other way to do it in pure HTML. This is what they were built for, it's like saying I want to fry an egg without an egg.

Comment: when you do this: is there any way you can have links clicked inside the iframe to change the whole window?

Answer (score 5):

If you're willing to use jquery, there is a handy jquery plugin called "inc".

I use it often for website prototyping, where I just want to present the client with static HTML with no backend layer that can be quickly created/edited/improved/re-presented

http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/inc-a-super-tiny-client-side-include-javascript-jquery-plugin.html

For example, things like the menu and footer need to be shown on every page, but you dont want to end up with a copy-and-paste-athon

You can include a page fragment as follows

```
<p class="inc:footer.htm"></p>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>example</title>
    <script> 
   $(function(){
       $('#filename').load("htmlfile.html");
   });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="filename">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't believe your code is going to work without include jquery.

Answer (score 4):

The best which i have got:
Include  in your js file and for including views you can add in this way

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Bootstrap</title>
    <!-- Your custom styles (optional) -->
    <link href="css/style_different.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"></script>
    <div class="">
      <div w3-include-html="templates/header.html"></div>
      <div w3-include-html="templates/dashboard.html"></div>
      <div w3-include-html="templates/footer.html"></div>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    w3IncludeHTML();
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Note: Brave browser and possible others disable this function unless the page is being hosted on a server.  The whole point of finding ways around normal SSI is for people who want to do web testing without a server and have it consistent on their server.  Thus this is a deal breaker.

Answer (score 3):

You can say that it is with PHP, but actually it has just one PHP command, all other files are just *.html.

1. You should have a file named .htaccess in your web server's /public_html directory, or in another directory, where your html file will be and  you will process one command inside it.
2. If you do not have it, (or it might be hidden (you should check this directory list by checking directory for hidden files)), you can create it with notepad, and just type one row in it:
   `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html`
3. Save this file with the name .htaccess and upload it to the server's main directory.
4. In your html file anywhere you want an external "meniu.html file to appear, add te command:
   `<?php include("meniu.html"); ?>`.

That's all!

Remark: all commands like `<? ...>` will be treated as php executables, so if your html have question marks, then you could have some problems.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for! I realized after reading this that I was doing `<?php echo include("meniu.html"); ?>.` When I removed the `echo` everything worked! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$.get("file.html", function(data){
    $("#div").html(data);
});
```

Comment: It's best if you add some commentary and not just toss code out there.

Answer (score 1):

In **2022**

In HTML without **iframe**

```
<div id="display" style="width: 100%;float: left;"></div>

<script>
  function load_anotherpage() {
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML =
      '<embed type="text/html" src="https://libcon.in/" width="100%" height="800" >';
  }

  load_anotherpage();
</script>
```

want more then use this [link](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/html/iframe-alternative/#:%7E:text=Use%20the%20object%20Tag%20as%20an%20Alternative%20to%20Iframe%20in%20HTML,-We%20can%20use&text=The%20object%20tag%20is%20an,the%20webpage%20to%20be%20embedded.)

Comment: Please don't use `<embed>`. It is deprecated, and has been for years. It is simply an abbreviation of `<iframe>` now.

Comment: @ethry [MDN doesn't appear to mark it as deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed), nor does [the W3 wiki](https://www.w3.org/html/wiki/Elements/embed). It does however seem to be roughly equivalent to the accepted answer of using an `object` element.

Comment: @Pharap I could've sworn it used to be deprecated.

Comment: @ethry Perhaps it was undeprecated? That does happen sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure to check out how to use [Angular includes](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_includes.asp) (using [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org)). It's pretty straight forward…

```
<body ng-app="">
  <div ng-include="'myFile.htm'"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NGINX over linux and want a pure bash/html, you can add a mask on your template and pipe the requests to use the sed command to do a replace by using a regullar expression.

Anyway I would rather have a bash script that takes from a templates folder and generate the final HTML.

Answer (score -3):

Best solution from nginx: http://sysoev.ru/nginx/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html

Answer (score -3):

confirmed roadkill, create a .htaccess file in the web root with a single line which allows you to add php code to a .html file.

AddType application/x-httpd-php .html