# Get HTML source of external webpage

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

I'm using stuff like 
`document.body.innerHTML` but I dont need my page source, I need it to get an external page source, since

`new Ajax.Updater ({success:'employerBox'}, '<%=appRootPath%>/userBoxHome.asp?isEmployer=true&ajaxLogin=home', {evalScripts: true});`

Is not working in IE and I need div `employerBox` to get updated with the content from `/userBoxHome.asp?isEmployer=true&ajaxLogin=home`

Any suggestions please or any functions that Im missing?

My idea, I know the code is wrong, is to do something like `document.body.innerHTML('userBoxHome.asp?isEmployer=true&ajaxLogin=home')`

Comment: Everything is on the same domain. -- just in case

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include an html page into an html page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676394/how-to-include-an-html-page-into-an-html-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function updateEmployerBox(){
    var div=$('employerBox');
    var url='<%=appRootPath%>/userBoxHome.asp?isEmployer=true&ajaxLogin=home';
    var options = {
        method:'get',
        onSuccess: function(transport){
            div.innerHTML=transport.responseText;
        },
        onFailure: function(transport){
            alert('Failed '+transport.responseText);
        }
    };//end options
    new Ajax.Request(url,options);
}
```

Comment: "Ajax.Request" is this Prototype? Just curious, a quick look on Google seems to think so.

Comment: It is prototype. The question is tagged as such, is this tag incorrect?

Answer (score -1):

You might want to check this out:

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/