# How to include html page in another?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I want to make a popup for index.html page. I have a demo, a popup will appear at bottom-right of webpage.
But my demo was wrote by jsp, not html.

```
<jsp:include page="popup.html" flush="true" ></jsp:include>
```

It work ok.

But in html, this line not work. I have tried:

```
<!--#include virtual="popup.html" -->
<!--#include file="popup.html" -->
```

but no popup appear.

So, Are there anyways to include popup.html. Thanks you!

Comment: Only through XHR, but it will entail an extra HTTP request.

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676394/how-to-include-an-html-page-into-an-html-page - look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/676409/983430) to see how to do it with jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

To use `<!--#include`, you need to make sure that your web server has [Server Side Includes](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html) enabled.

You could also use a server-based language like PHP which will do this using functions like [`readfile()`](http://php.net/readfile).

In pure HTML, I suspect your only option would be to include the second HTML file inside an [`<iframe>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp).  It's by no means an ideal solution, but if nothing else works, this may.