# "Template" of sorts for HTML website

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website which currently resides in the form of HTML files in my server's folder. I have some elements that are present on each page, and have to be the same, e.g. the navbar. When I add a new link to the navbar, if I want to make that effective for every page, I have to go around every single file replacing code. Is there a way to make the code be "inserted" from a file? I know something like that is possible with `<?php include() ?>`, but how would I be able to do that without server-side scripting?

EDIT: jQuery and other libraries are fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to go without the server-side is javascript. See Aviatrix's post for a JS template.

In your case, and only if server-side IS ACCEPTABLE for you, I would rather go for a more generic approach; instead of having your navbar in each file/page, create your navbar one time in a separate file, and use it in every page (php or other ssi approach is needed).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is too much for your use case, but there is the [handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) library available for Javascript and HTML templating. Of course you would need to program Javascript then.

Answer (score 0):

Form what I undarstand you are in need for a JS templating engine of sorts :

http://handlebarsjs.com/

is what might fit your needs

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do

```
<!--#include virtual="path/file.html" -->
```

also, see [How to include an HTML page into another HTML page without frame/iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676394/how-to-include-an-html-page-into-an-html-page)

Comment: This may need to be turned on in your web servers configuration.

Comment: That's pretty much server-side scripting.

Comment: This is an IIS-only functionality, although I don't recall if it was only for ASP pages or all pages served through IIS.

Comment: Question: for that, do I need to name my files `file.php`, or can it be `.html`?

Answer (score 0):

Of course that is possible. For example with jQuery. See the `.load()` function [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/).