# How to have a common header and footer in a HTML CSS web app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been using ASP.NET MVC for all my projects and have been using `@Html.Partial("_header")` where ever I wanted to include a common static html in any of my pages.

But now I am working in a pure HTML CSS and JS web app. Here I am not using any server side technology, just a set of static contents.

Here in the site I have the following layout

> ----- HEADER -----
>
> ----- Changing Content ------
>
> ----- FOOTER ------

So, here is what I want, I want to somehow do the thing I used to achieve `@Html.Partial()`

One way I know is using IFRAMES, is there any other better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have come across this situation while making chrome extension.

What i did was storing the header footer in variable of js file and then appending that to body using jquery.i was using that js file where i wanted my header and footer to be.i just used to add js in script of head.....Boom i got my fixed header footer in page.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/omefu4/42)**

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript">      </script>
 <script>
 function appendheaderfooter(){
 var header="<div style='position:fixed;top:0px;background-color:aqua;'>header html</div>";
 var footer="<div style='position:fixed;bottom:0px;background-color:aqua;'>footer html</div>"
 $("body").append(header+footer);
}
  window.onload = appendheaderfooter;
</script>
<style>
div{width:100%;}
</style>
</head>
<body><br/>
<p>Content goes here</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so the page must be shifting right, just before the js is loaded ?

Comment: no...i wrote those html in such a way that they remained sticked to header and footer accordingly.so had no problem of any shifting.

Comment: What happens when JavaScript is disabled? c.f. "Progressive Enhancement" / "Graceful Degradation"

Comment: @kwah:he is using pure html css and javascript....everything fails if javascript is disabled.to be honest i never came across the situation where javascripts are disabled on page.

Comment: yea javascript will always be enabled in my case. Thanks milind, can you share some code, a sample/fiddle ?

Comment: gimme a minute...ill make bin for you.

Answer (score 1):

If your web app is going to be hosted on a web server supporting Server Side Includes (for example Apache) you can just add `<!--#include virtual="/header.html" -->`
Depending on your web server, you might need to enable the SSI first (`Options +Includes` in .htaccess on apache)

Answer (score 0):

### Frames

Frames used to be the way to go, but as time has gone by they have fallen out of favour with developers for one reason or another - note [this article](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/avoid-frame-based-layouts-in-favor-of-alternative-designs/6109221) from 2006!

Fortunately, you seem to be in favour of avoiding frames :)

### SSI over JavaScript

Secondly, Server-Side Includes (SSI) or some other server-based "include" is favoured over JavaScript, though I accept that this is not necessarily a "pure" HTML/JS/CSS solution.

The format of an SSI statement is as follows:
`<!--#include virtual="../quote.txt" -->`

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/article.php/3473341/SSI-The-Include-Command.htm

There are many answers that reflect this view on SO - for example, the first three that appeared in searching are
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418503/common-header-footer-with-static-html),
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676394/how-to-include-an-html-page-into-an-html-page) and 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398089/template-of-sorts-for-html-website) ...

*Note that the accepted answer for that last one is recommending a JS solution, but the final paragraph states a preference for something server-side..*

### Compilation of your HTML code (my preferred option)

It has been a while since I have needed to create a "pure" HTML/CSS/JS website, but when doing so my preference is to keep the code modular and "compile" the HTML before deployment.

Although it requires a little additional work prior to deployment, it produces the "purest" output to be used within deployed code. You write your code as normal, use a little magic to indicate what you want included and where and then you "compile" this code into bog-standard HTML/CSS/JS files that are deployed onto your site.

This brings the ease and simplicity of using templated header/footer/menu-bar/sidebar files, with the tradeoff of needing to compile the HTML code beforehand.

SASS uses Ruby on Rails to perform this compilation. Unfortunately, a reference for its HTML equivalent is escaping me at this particular moment in time, so I shall update my answer as/when I relocate it.

Answer (score -1):

Are you open to use [Frameset](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp), though it is not supported in HTML5?