# How to get header HTML code included in all .html files

Tags: html, header

I have a simple website, in which I've written the code that's about the header.
This is included in the `index.html`. Now that I want to add another `.html` file, how can I have the header related code, included into all the HTML files?

A simple copy paste will surely do the job, but is it a correct solution?

*Developing in Ubuntu, using Sublime Text with H5BP and Compass.*

Comment: PHP is what I use. I write my HTML in PHP, to a page called `header.php`, then I `include 'header.php';` in `index.php` and `echo` the `$varible` I store the HTML into, onto every page.

Comment: First of all, HTML is no code ^_^ Ontopic: You could, like @PHPglue say, use PHP. But I think this will be overload for only the include function. You could also use an ajax call and get the content of your HTML file. [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676394/how-to-include-an-html-page-into-an-html-page)

Comment: Using a server-side language is DEFINITELY the way to go for this. But you could also have blocking XMLHttpRequest that writes it to the document

Comment: It's also popular to have everything on one page, with a query string determining the page. The JavaScript would read the query string, and depending on it, simply change the URL of an iframe in the center

Comment: @Markasoftware: But since you are talking about JavaScript, you mean client-side, right? Wouldn't this be bad for the loading time of the page?

Comment: yes. It would. but you could always have a placeholder element that takes up space and just populate it once the request loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use PHP:

```
// header.php
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
function https(){
  $sv = $_SERVER;
  if(!isset($sv['HTTPS'])){
    header("LOCATION:https://{$sv['SERVER_NAME']}{$sv['PHP_SELF']}"); die();
  }
}
function http(){
  $sv = $_SERVER;
  if(isset($sv['HTTPS'])){
    unset($_SERVER['HTTPS']);
    header("LOCATION:http://{$sv['SERVER_NAME']}{$sv['PHP_SELF']}"); die();
  }
}
$doc = "<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
      <meta name='keywords' content='put your site keywords here' />";
$main = " </head>
<body class='njs'>
  <div id='head'>
    <div id='menu'>
      <nav class='tabs'>
        <a href='index.php' id='hm'>Home</a>
        <a href='page2.php' id='p2'>Page 2</a>
        <a href='page3.php' id='p3'>Page 3</a>
        <a href='page4.php' id='p4'>Page 4</a>
        <a href='page5.php' id='p5'>Page 5</a>
        <a href='page6.php' id='p6'>Page 6</a>
        <a href='page7.php' id='p7'>Page 7</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div id='content'>";
 ?>
```

Now, put `header.php` in a `restricted` folder, in the same location as `index.html` for added security, then change `index.html` to `index.php`. Now `index.php`:

```
// index.php
<?php
include_once 'restricted/header.php'; http(); // could be https() for SSL
echo "$doc
    <title>Whatever - Home</title>
    <meta name='description' content='Whatever - Home' />
    <style type='text/css'>
      @import 'common.css'; @import 'index.css';
    </style>
$main";
?>
  <!-- put your content here -->
  <!-- don't forget to close the `id='content'` div -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some questions coming up, brace yourself! :P (I'm new to the web developing world, that's why.) So, 1. why it is needed to set the timezone? 2. What do the functions `http()` and `https()` do, and do I absolutely need them for this small _about me_ website? 3. Why do we use these variables? (I've achieved splitting the header and home content by copying all the header-relative lines to a `header.php` file and then including this file to the `index.php` file. Just that, I didn't use any variables with `echo`.) 4. When you say restricted, with permissions like `600`?

Comment: `1.` It's to make sure your MySQL database, that you will probably make has the correct time - Change that to your timezone. `2.` http() forces an insecure protocol, so the user is redirected if they are using https://. Note that some Browsers will not change back to an insecure protocol if you move to an https page on the same site. https() forces a secure protocol, so if you have purchased an SSL (Secure Sockets Layer) certificate the user cannot get on that page at all without https://.

Comment: Thank you for the reply to the comment. I've tried simply assigning the contents of `<head>` (+the `head` tags), as you posted ( `$head = " HTML here ";` and at the index.html typed this: `<?php include_once 'head.php'; http(); echo "$head"; ?>` and all I get is a blank page, whose source is cut up to the point of the echo (before the `echo`). What have I done wrong?

Comment: `3.` I echo the entire String. In PHP you can put simple variables into double quotes, and they will be evaluated before the String is output. `4.` I'm not sure about 600, but Read, Write and Execute(Directory) should be off for Users and on for Owner.

Comment: `head.php` would have to be in the same folder as for than `include_once` to work,  and your page needs to be called `index.php` not `index.html`.

Comment: Yes, I have it `index.php`, sorry. The problem were the double quotes into at the HTML. I've replaced them with singe quotes and echoing the whole header, worked fine. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could also ajax to load in the header into the separate pages, if you didn't want to deal with php.  Just have the header html in a separate file and do an ajax call on dom load and then apply the response to the container of the header in the page you are using.