# Add new page in same HTML file

Tags: html, dreamweaver

Anyone knows is it possible to add a new page in the same HTML file in Dreamweaver CS6? If yes, how? Also, how to make a button open another page in the HTML file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include an html page into an html page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676394/how-to-include-an-html-page-into-an-html-page)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the first question. Are you looking to use the same page and add new content? In this case you would need to use a language such as PHP and call in dynamic content from a database.

The answer to your second question is to use an html link instead of a button:-

```
<a href="link.com" target="_blank" class="button">link here</a>
```

And style it to look like a button. If you're not familiar with this process, this site may help:-

[CSS Button Generator](http://www.cssbuttongenerator.com/)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Button to new page:

```
<form action="http://google.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Go to Google">
</form>
```

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link))

HTML page in page:

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
```

([Source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp))