# How to reuse HTML across entire site

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a header using HTML and Bootstrap and I want the header to appear on all pages of my site. Is there a way to do something similar to a CSS style sheet but instead of CSS, reusing HTML?

Comment: If you're using a server-side scripting language like PHP, you can include your header snippet of HTML in multiple files.

Comment: I'm just using HTML, CSS, Bootstrap, JS and jQuery, no server side languages (to my limited knowledge)

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676394/how-to-include-an-html-page-into-another-html-page-without-frame-iframe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include another HTML file in a HTML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file)

Comment: Given that you are learning I'll suggest you go to *Angular* OR *React*. By the time you learn HTML CSS ... you will realise that using a framework like the above mention will save u a lot of time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way I believe is to use jQuery.

See jQuery docs [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load)

one.html:

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#header").load("two.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="header"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

two.html:

```
<p> Put your header in here </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to store jquery, you can use a [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)

```html
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script>$(document).ready(function () { $("header").load("assets/header.html"); });</script>
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <header></header> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript as on: {% extends "xxx.html" %}

Answer (score -2):

You can use an `<iframe>` to change the content that is displayed, and only code the surrounding header/footer/etc. only once. There seems to be some uneasy feelings about using them floating around, so I would do some research on that before I committed to it.

`HTML include` is a recent feature you could try as well. Otherwise, it's gonna be good ol' fashioned `ctrl-c` `ctrl-v`.

Comment: Realy, copy  / paste? A maintenance nightmare! A good developer is a lazy developer...