# Add CSS attributes to html afterward

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a website with a menu bar stored in another file (solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676394/how-to-include-an-html-page-into-another-html-page-without-frame-iframe)). I also have the css stored in a seperate file, linked to the menu bar:

`<!--#include file="menu.html" -->`

Each page on my website get's highlighted if it's the **current** page. However, Since my html is in a seperate file, I can't just add `class="current"` or something similar to that. This is what I came up with:

- add css to each site selecting `ul:nth-child(n)` that adds all needed css.

If I change the *order* of the elements, everything will be messed up!
Is there a better way to add css later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an `id` to the body of each page and another one to each menu item, and then apply the highlight styles when the menu `id` is contained in their associated body `id`.

For example if you have an about page you would use:

```
<body id="about-page">

</body>
```

The menu would have id's for each item:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li id="main"><a hef="/">My page</a></li>
  <li id="shop"><a hef="/">Shop</a></li>
  <li id="about"><a hef="/">About me</a></li>
</ul>
```

And you would put the style rules in this way:

```
.menu {
  /* menu styles */
}

#main-page #main, #shop-page #shop, #about-page #about {
  /* styles for highlight the current page */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used an id scheme similar to my website's page layout, and applied a javascript function that split's the query into sections, and adds css to the desired id(s).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="menu.css" type="text/css"/>
<nav id="menu_wrap">
      <ul>
        <li><a id="home" href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a id="school" href="">School</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a id="trinomial" href="https://reteps.tk/school/trinomial_calculator">Trinomial Calculator</a></li>
            <li><a id="radical" href="https://reteps.tk/school/radical_calculator">Radical Calculator</a></li>
            <li><a id="grades" href="https://reteps.tk/school/grades_calculator">Grade Calculator</a></li>
            <li><a id="trig" href="https://reteps.tk/school/trig_calculator">Trig Calculator</a></li>
            <li><a id="kahoot" href="https://reteps.tk/school/kahoot_bot">Kahoot Bot</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/blog/home">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="/other">Other</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://github.com/reteps">Github</a></li>
      </ul>
</nav>
<script>
  var path = window.location.pathname;
  if (path == "/") {
    document.getElementById("home").style.background = "#27e8e8";
  } else {
    var sections = path.split("/");
    for (var i = 1;i < sections.length;i++) {
      document.getElementById(sections[i].split("_")[0]).style.background = "#27e8e8";
    }
  }
</script>
```